# Definition of Floer complex in Floer's "Morse theory for Lagrangian intersections"

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology, fukaya-category

I am moving the first steps into Lagrangian Floer theory and I am trying to understand the construction, as in the original paper, for the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (no orientations) and $\pi_2(P,L) = 0$.

In *"Morse theory for Lagrangian intersections"* Floer defines the complex as the abelian group generated by
$$I(L,\phi) := \left\{ x \in L \cap L' \ : \ [\phi_t(x)] = 0 \in \pi_1(P,L) \right\}$$
with $L' := \phi_1(L)$.
In the same vein, he defines the space of paths as
$$\Omega(L,\phi) := \left\{ z :[0,1] \to M \ : \ z(0) \in L, \ z(1) \in L', \ [\phi_t(z(t))] = 0 \ \text{in } \pi_1(P,L) \right\}$$

Elsewhere I've seen the complex defined simply as the group generated by intersection points $L \cap L'$ (when $L \pitchfork L'$).

**Q1: Why the complex can't be taken simply as generated by $L \cap L'$?**
In other words, why the need of the topological condition $[\phi_t(x)] = 0$? The same questions holds for the path space, why not take $\Omega(L,L')$?

A related question is the following

**Q2: Can we say that Floer constructed a cohomology for a pair of Lagrangians?**
In his paper Floer constructs a cohomology $FH(L,\phi)$. Does his construction "just works" for two different Lagrangians $L_1,L_2$, always in the hypothesis of no bubbling ($\pi_2 = 0$) and $\mathbb{Z}_2$-coefficients?

Thanks in advance

Comment: @ChrisGerig The M was a typo, now there should be only Ps. I tried to clarify. By "that" topological condition I mean the condition(s) involving $\pi_1$.